# Launch Firefox, get Google Maps session

Tags: linux

Ubuntu 10.04, Firefox 3.6.24

I have a Pipe of commands which displays a single street address.
I then...

- List item

  - copy the address to the clipboard
  - launch Firefox
  - go to Google Maps
  - paste the address into the search window,
  - press ENTER
  - view a map of the neighborhood

Is there a way to automate this multi-step process?

The ideal solution would have *exactly* the same result as the multi-step process. It would give the user a Google Maps session. This is better than a static map because it provides a dynamic map (shift in any direction, zoom in or out) and the option of asking for directions from Point A to Point B.

I poked around in the Google Maps Playground ...
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/
... but did not find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I follow what exactly you're doing, but you don't really need to use the Google Maps API for this.  You should look into coding a batch script to output the hyperlinks directly (i.e., no copy paste) using the logic below.

You can take the Google Maps URL:
http://maps.google.com/

And append the street address (URL encoded) as a URL parameter:
[http://maps.google.com/**maps?q=*1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA***](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=1600%20Amphitheatre%20Parkway,%20Mountain%20View,%20CA)

Clicking on the link will take you to the map page.